# grunt-config-requirejs MUCH slower than r.js on command line

Tags: gruntjs, requirejs

I wanted to post this as an issue on grunt-contrib-requirejs github but it seems they are not accepting issue submissions.

When I run r.js it takes about 3s but when I do a single grunt task using this module with exactly the same options it takes 13s. I have used time-grunt to analyse this so I'm fairly confident that this time does not include grunt setup time:

```
loading tasks       3.2s
requirejs:compile  13.3s
```

Here's my config:

```
    requirejs: {
      compile: {
        options: {
          mainConfigFile: 'scaling-tool/js/main.js',
          baseUrl: 'scaling-tool/js',
          removeCombined: true,
          findNestedDependencies: true,
          dir: 'scaling-tool/dist',
          name: 'main',
          optimize: 'none'
        }
      }
    },
```

Without the `optimize: 'none'` option set it takes 25s!

EDIT: I'm now dealing with this by using grunt-shell to run the r.js command, but that's a workaround not an answer

Answer (score 0):

The amount of time for run Grunt's tasks is growing fast by how many task has you defined, anyway i understand your situation is for that task individually, one question: you need that task all the time? Only in production mode? If that is your situation you can omit/register/run that task all time and finishing my intervention here, i can tell you two options:

1. Ommit that task with one parameter in your command line execution
2. Get your assets combined using command line r.js option like you say, but you can call this command line call with grunt-exec in your Gruntfile.